# how to make the object bounce back?

Tags: flash

```
for (var k:int = 0; k < 1; k++)
        {
            money = new Money;
            money.x = X[chooseSpawnPoint()];
            money.y = moneysourceY;
            money.dx = RandomRange(-5,5);
            money.dy = RandomRange(-5,5);
            Config.CurrentStage.addChild(money);

            moneyVector.push(money);
        }

private function Update(evt:Event)
    {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < moneyVector.length; i++)
        {               
            moneyVector[i].x += moneyVector[i].dx;
            moneyVector[i].y += moneyVector[i].dy;
            if (moneyVector[i].hitTestObject(character))
            {
                Config.CurrentStage.removeChild(moneyVector[i]);
                moneyVector.splice(i, 1);
                moneyscore +=  400;
                moneytext.text = "Money : " + moneyscore.toString();
                money = new Money  ;
                money.dx = RandomRange(-5,5);
                money.dy = RandomRange(-5,5);
                money.x = X[chooseSpawnPoint()];
                money.y = moneysourceY;
                Config.CurrentStage.addChild(money);
                moneyVector.push(money);

            }
            if ( moneyVector[i].x < 0 ) {
                moneyVector[i].x = moneyVector[i].x + -1 * moneyVector[i].dx //<-- cannot bounce back
            }

        }
    }
```

When the object collide with wall, object.Y increasing but object.X remain constantly instead of object.X should be increasing too.
How to make the object bounce back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only making it bounce back when X is less than 0... So what is happening is that the object hits the wall (x is less than 0) moves back to just past 0 (actually to 0 because you have if it is less than 0) and then starts to go back toward the wall again until it is less than 0 (almost instantly).  So you will see the object just stuck at the wall (x=0).

One way that I tend to approach this is store a different direction variable that is either +1 or -1.  Once the object passes 0 (x<0) i set the direction to +1.  Once the object hits however far I want to go to the right I set the direction back to -1.  Then every time I am increasing the x position by the movement speed I multiply by direction which will only change the direciton not the speed.

```
private function Update(evt:Event) 
{ 

    for (var i:int = 0; i < moneyVector.length; i++) 
    {     
       // Figure out what direction to move           
        if ( moneyVector[i].x < 0 ) { 
            direction = 1; 
        } else if(moneyVector[i].x > maxX) {
             direction = -1;
        }
        // Multiply by direction to move the correct way
        moneyVector[i].x += moneyVector[i].dx * direction;
        moneyVector[i].y += moneyVector[i].dy; 
        if (moneyVector[i].hitTestObject(character)) 
        { 
            Config.CurrentStage.removeChild(moneyVector[i]); 
            moneyVector.splice(i, 1); 
            moneyscore +=  400; 
            moneytext.text = "Money : " + moneyscore.toString(); 
            money = new Money  ; 
            money.dx = RandomRange(-5,5); 
            money.dy = RandomRange(-5,5); 
            money.x = X[chooseSpawnPoint()]; 
            money.y = moneysourceY; 
            Config.CurrentStage.addChild(money); 
            moneyVector.push(money); 

        } 

    } 
}
```

Don't forget to store direction as a varible for each moneyVector index and set whatever you want your maxX to be instead of where I have "maxX"

Comment: i got it, i knew the problem. You were right, i am only making it bounce back when X is less than 0
i should change the speed and direction into negative of original instead of moneyVector[i].x = moneyVector[i].x + -1 * moneyVector[i].dx